# Why does Cron scheduler not working in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Note:** **i'm using laravel 5.0**

I have executed this commond "* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1" like mentioned in documentation of laravel but cron still not working this my kernel file:

```
<?php namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\InstagramAutopost',
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('instagramautopost')
             ->everyFiveMinutes()
             ->withoutOverlapping();
}
}
```

and this is my InstagramAutopost.php file in Commands:

```
use App\Export;
use App\Insta;
use Auth;
use Response;
use App\Vehicle;
use View;
use Instagram;
use App\Libraries\UserPreferences;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Libraries\Info;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class InstagramAutopost extends Command {

 /**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'instagramautopost';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Instagram Autopost';

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */

 public function handle() {

    $vehicles_id = Vehicle::where(['user_id' => Auth::id()])->get();
    $numVehicles = count($vehicles_id);

    for ($i=0; $i < $numVehicles ; $i++) {
        $vExport = Export::where(['v_id' => $vehicles_id[$i]['id']])->first();

        if (!$vExport || ($vehicles_id[$i]['last_modified'] > $vExport['instagram_date'])) {
            $settings = \App\Insta::where(['user_id' => Auth::id()])->first();
            if($settings){
                $vInfo = Vehicle::where(['id' => $vehicles_id[$i]['id']])->first();

                $img = $this->get_main_photo($vInfo['photos'], 400, 300, V12_IMAGES_URL . '/' . Auth::user()->photos_directory . '/' . $vInfo['id'] . "/");
                if($img && getimagesize($img) ){

                    $price = ($vInfo['internet_specials']=='yes' and $vInfo['featured_price']!=0)?$vInfo['featured_price']:$vInfo['price'];
                    $msg = $vInfo['year'].' '.$vInfo['make_name'].' '.$vInfo['model'].' $'.$price;

                    /////// CONFIG ///////
                    $username = $settings->username;
                    $password = $settings->password;

                    $debug = false;
                    $photo = $img ;
                    $info  = new Info(Auth::id(), $vehicles_id[$i]['id']);
                    $caption = $msg.' '.$info->getDomain() . "/inventory/view/" . $vehicles_id[$i]['id'];    

                    $instagrame = new Instagram($username, $password, $debug);

                    //Login
                    try {
                        $instagrame->login();

                    } catch (InstagramException $e) {
                        exit();
                    }

                    //Upload photo
                    try {

                        $instagrame->uploadPhoto($img, $caption);

                        //update exports
                        $exp = Export::where(['v_id' => $vehicles_id[$i]['id']])->first();
                        if(!$exp){
                            $exp = new Export;
                            $exp->v_id = $vehicles_id[$i]['id'];
                        }
                        $exp->instagram = 'yes';
                        $exp->instagram_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $exp->save();


                    } catch (Exception $e) {

                    }   
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

/**
* Get the main photo of a vehicle
*
* @return Response
*/
public function get_main_photo($photos, $width, $height, $path = '') {
    if ($photos != '') {
        $ar_photos = unserialize($photos);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($ar_photos); $i++) {
            if ($ar_photos[$i]['main'] == 'yes') {
                return (empty($width) ? $path . $ar_photos[$i]['photo'] : $path . str_ireplace('.jpg', '_' . $width . $height . '.jpg', $ar_photos[$i]['photo']));
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
    }

 }
```

I want if it's there something wrong.

Comment: Does the code work if you run it *outside* of cron? What do your cron logs say? You're breaking Instagram's terms by using their private API, so maybe they just blocked you.

Comment: I test it and its working good with controller

Comment: Does it work if you run `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run` manually via the command line?

Comment: I don't have the access to SSH but the responsible of it he told me that the cron enabled . so when i move the scripte from the controller to the command is not working

Comment: I told you that there is a responsible of SSH who charged to enable the cron i just give him the full path of artisan

Comment: If you don't have access, you should ask the responsible person to debug. There's not much we can do if you yourself don't have basic access to troubleshoot things.

Answer (score 2):

Your `InstagramAutopost.php` (as shown above) is not a valid `Command`

The class needs to extend `Command` not `Controller` and implement the `handle()` method, as well as a few other required properties.

You can use `php artisan make:command` to create a shell of a proper command and then copy-paste into it.

Comment: it's just a mistake, i copied the wrong code sorry . now i edited the code

Comment: Please tell me like you i used to function handle() and get_main_photo(), is that possible to use anothet function with handle() function or in this file i should use just handle function ?

Comment: The code looks fine. And yes, you can call other functions from `handle()` as you have. Unfortunately, you'll have to figure this out with the person who runs the server.

Comment: thank you very much i found the problem, it was a file in config folder who breaks artisan from working, i figure that this file contains url helper and like we know using url helper in config files breaks Artisan.